# Convert Indented Text List to HTML List (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I am attempting to create a jQuery script which will convert an indented text list of arbitrary length and depth into a properly formatted HTML list.  The lists on which I will be running this script are simple tree structures for directories.  Within the tree structures, folders are denoted by a semicolon following the folder name (and files have no ending punctuation).  Given this, I would like to attach a `<span class="folder"></span>` or `<span class="file"></span>` to the lines as appropriate.

I've found it to be fairly easy to generate most of the structure, but I cannot seem to get the recursion (which I suspect will be necessary) down to ensure that the tags are properly nested.  The page on which this will be implemented will include the most recent (i.e., 3.0.3) version of Bootstrap, so feel free to use any of its functionality.  I have about two dozen (generally abortive) fragments of code which I've tried or which I'm currently attempting to tweak to produce the desired result.  Instead of posting a mass of (likely unhelpful) code, I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/3ZuEK/1/) with the basic form which will be used for input/output, a bit of jQuery, and an example list and some external libraries loaded.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pleas also post code you have attempted , that got you most of the way

Comment: can you not get your data into json? Using same nested properties in json, not hard to recursively loop over children...http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/pCsZ3/

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for the JSON recommendation.  I'll definitely look at that for future implementation purposes.  However, right now I'm just trying to create a simple form that can be used to convert indented text to HTML lists.  I actually managed to find a script which does so, but, unfortunately, it's written in CoffeeScript and does **not** seem to convert well to standard JavaScript.  Here's the script: http://codepen.io/jamiely/pen/AbEjd.

Comment: there are online converters to make it easy  http://cs2js.nodejitsu.com/

Comment: That one appears to have worked, @charlietfl.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I copied it to your fiddle and it seems to work.

```
var indentedToHtmlList = function indentedToHtmlList (text, indentChar, folderChar, listType, showIcons) {
  indentChar = indentChar || '\t';
  folderChar = folderChar || ':';
  listType = listType || 'ul';
  showIcons = !!showIcons;

  var lastDepth,
      lines = text.split(/\r?\n/),
      output = '<' + listType + '>\n',
      depthCounter = new RegExp('^(' + indentChar + '*)(.*)');

  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var splitted = lines[i].match(depthCounter),
        indentStr = splitted[1],
        fileName = splitted[2],
        currentDepth = (indentStr === undefined) ? 0 : (indentStr.length / indentChar.length),
        isFolder = (fileName.charAt(fileName.length - 1) === folderChar);

    if (isFolder) {
      fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length -1);
    }

    if (lastDepth === currentDepth) {
      output += '</li>\n';
    } else if (lastDepth > currentDepth) {
      while (lastDepth > currentDepth) {
        output += '</li>\n</' + listType + '>\n</li>\n';
        lastDepth--;
      }
    } else if (lastDepth < currentDepth) {
      output += '\n<' + listType + '>\n';
    }

    output += '<li>';
    if (showIcons) {
      output += '<span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-' +
      (isFolder ? 'folder-open' : 'file') +
      '"></span> ';
    }
    output += fileName;

    lastDepth = currentDepth;
  }

  while (lastDepth >= 0) {
    output += '\n</li>\n</' + listType + '>';
    lastDepth--;
  }

  return output;
};
```

Comment: While I suspect the issue is end-user error, I couldn't get that script to work with my JSFiddle.  Mind taking a look at the current version: http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/3ZuEK/5/, and perhaps forking it to get your script working?  Your script seems a more elegant solution than the (somewhat questionable) CoffeeScript solution I posted, *supra*.

Comment: I noticed the `span`'s weren't closed, but that was an easy fix.  In case you were wondering, I'm using the `span`'s to add Glyphicons.

Comment: So, I'm sure you noticed that my JSFiddle has a checkbox for adding Glyphicons and a dropdown for selecting between `ol` and `ul` lists.  Any idea how I would go about incorporating those options into your script?  If you aren't familiar with Glyphicons, the ones I'd be using are applied with the following classes: `glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open` for the folders and `glyphicon glyphicon-file` for the files, which are simply added to the `div`'s.

Comment: I changed the code above. Basically I added additional parameters for the list type and whether to show the icons. To use it you can read the values of the checkbox and the dropdown and pass them to the function: http://jsfiddle.net/bFq7H/3/ (I added ```value``` attributes to the select options and an ```id``` attribute to the dropdown to make it easier ;) )

Comment: Looks like I may have found a bug in the script.  It seems to have some trouble with properly nesting lists which go beyond three levels in depth.  Mind taking a look at it to see what's going on?  Here's some text for testing purposes: http://pastebin.com/nsj8xkEZ.

Comment: I've managed to narrow down the issue a bit further: It seems that the script will properly nest lists of arbitrary (seemingly infinite) depth; however, issues appear when the script has to jump several levels in depth.

Comment: Here is an indented list in plain text: http://pastebin.com/k9WExYTe;
the output from the script: http://pastebin.com/9VHw1tkZ; and
the analysis (by BBEdit) including syntax errors: http://pastebin.com/hvztyN7Y.

Comment: Here's a marked-up version of the output from the last comment, with notes on what appears to be going wrong with the syntax: http://pastebin.com/G8Z8XhVK.  As you can see, there appears to be a pattern to how the elements are inserted improperly.  At least to me, it appears that it is inserting additional, extraneous `</li>` tags and placing closing `</ul>` tags for nested lists too far down in the hierarchy.

Comment: The additional ```</li>``` is in the first while loop. Just add one ```</li>``` right before the while loop and remove this ```</li>``` inside the while loop (the first one at the beginning of the string). but I can't see the problem with the ```</ul>```s , sorry :/

Comment: I'll open up another thread on the topic and see if someone can figure out what's going on.  Unfortunately, I don't know nearly enough JavaScript even to know where to start.  I'll make sure to post back here if a solution is found.

Comment: Code had serious problems when the jump between indents was > 1, resulting in arbitrary placed <li>s. I fixed it by adding some conditions (see var depthJump): jsfiddle.net/andsynchrony/bFq7H/10 - might help, @Zyniker . This should work for anyone just looking for a solution on generally converting indended plain text lists into html syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You could use spans and classes to denote files and folders, but you should consider using ul and li elements, they were built for that.

The whole list should be enclosed within an ul element. Each entry on the top level list should create an li element inside of the main element. If the element is a folder, then it should also append another ul. This is where you'll need recursion to allow proper nesting.

However, if you intend to use indentation (no pun indented) the tab and or whitespace parsing is a problem by itself which I'm not solving in this answer. For the sake of this example, I'll just pretend you have a magic function that turns text into a parsed list called MyList, and that files that belong to a folder are whatever lies after the first semicolon of each list element.

```
var turnTextIntoList=function(AText) {
    //magic stuff;
    return SomeList;
};

var populateList=function(AList) {
    var mainelement=jQuery('<ul></ul>');
    for(element in AList) { 
        var the_li=jQuery('<li></li>');
        if(element.indexOf(';')!=-1) {
             the_li.append('<span class="file">'+element+'</span>');
        } else {
              var thefolder=element.split(';')
              the_li.append('<span class="folder">'+thefolder[0]+'</span>');
              the_li.append(populateList(turnTextIntoList(thefolder[1])));
        } 
        mainelement.append(the_li);
    }
    return mainelement;
};

var MyList=turnTextIntoList(MyText);
jQuery('#targetdiv').append(populateList(MyList));
```

See, the recursion part is where you do

```
the_li.append(populateList(turnTextIntoList(thefolder[1])));
```

which will keep drilling into nesting levels until it reaches a file so it can start its way back.

Comment: I actually do intend to use `ul` and `li` elements, the `span`'s are simply for the purpose of attaching glyphs, actually.  I see your script does append the `span`'s; incidentally, that's exactly what I intended.

What I'm trying to get the script to do, and what I suspect yours nearly does, is properly convert the indented text into an HTML list with appropriate markup.  In essence, exactly what this script does: http://codepen.io/jamiely/pen/AbEjd, but preferably with jQuery not CoffeeScript (and, yes, I tried to convert that script using CoffeeScript's tool on their website and it failed).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that someone already created a [script](http://codepen.io/jamiely/pen/AbEjd) which does this.  Unfortunately, that script is in CoffeeScript, not JavaScript.  However, there are a number online converters which will convert from CoffeeScript to JavaScript.  Thanks to @charlietfl who provided a link to a working converter, *supra*.

Here is the converted, working code:

```
var bind, blank, convert, index, li, lineToMap, linesToMaps, parse, parseTuples, ptAccum, runConvert, tabCount, ul, ulEnd;

convert = function(text) {
  return parse(text.split('\n'));
};

li = function(t) {
  var html;
  html = "<li>" + t['line'] + "</li>";
  ptAccum.push(html);
  return html;
};

ul = function(t) {
  return ptAccum.push("<ul>" + (li(t)));
};

ulEnd = function() {
  return ptAccum.push("</ul>");
};

ptAccum = [];

index = 0;

parse = function(lines) {
  var ts;
  ts = linesToMaps(lines);
  ptAccum = ["<ul>"];
  index = 0;
  parseTuples(ts, 0);
  ulEnd();
  return ptAccum.join("\n");
};

parseTuples = function(tuples, level) {
  var stop, _p, _results;
  stop = false;
  _p = function() {
    var curLevel, t;
    t = tuples[index];
    curLevel = t['level'];
    index++;
    if (curLevel === level) {
      return li(t);
    } else if (curLevel < level) {
      index--;
      return stop = true;
    } else {
      ul(t);
      parseTuples(tuples, level + 1);
      return ulEnd();
    }
  };
  _results = [];
  while (!stop && index < tuples.length) {
    _results.push(_p());
  }
  return _results;
};

tabCount = function(line) {
  var c, count, i, inc, isTab, tc;
  tc = 0;
  c = '\t';
  count = 0;
  if (line) {
    count = line.length;
  }
  i = 0;
  isTab = function() {
    return c === '\t';
  };
  inc = function() {
    c = line.charAt(i);
    if (isTab()) {
      tc++;
    }
    return i++;
  };
  while (isTab() && i < count) {
    inc();
  }
  return tc;
};

lineToMap = function(line) {
  return {
    line: line,
    level: tabCount(line)
  };
};

blank = function(line) {
  return !line || line.length === 0 || line.match(/^ *$/);
};

linesToMaps = function(lines) {
  var line, _i, _len, _results;
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = lines.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    line = lines[_i];
    if (!(blank(line))) {
      _results.push(lineToMap(line));
    }
  }
  return _results;
};

runConvert = function() {
  var result;
  result = convert($('#textarea-plain-text').val());
  $('#textarea-converted-text').val(result);
  return $('#div-converted-text').html(result);
};

bind = function() {
  return $('#list-conversion-button').click(runConvert);
};

$(bind);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zyniker/3ZuEK/5/)

Comment: There are, however, two remaining problems:
1. this code doesn't eliminate all of the indentations in the original plain-text list (and, if I'm not mistaken, tidy() won't be sufficient here, as it won't strip the whitespace (i.e., the tabs) which are encased in `li`'s) and
2. this code does not add the desired `<span>`'s.

Comment: Found an error in the script, it appears that it duplicates the top-level `li` item whenever it creates a new `ul` (with the sole exception being the top-level `ul`, oddly).