# Generate a folder structure from an array of strings

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying different possibilities but I am unsure how I can achieve a proper `<ul><li>` structure for my scenario when using jQuery.

I am looping through the `filesList` array using `forEach` and appending `<ul>` which gives me the following result:

```js
var filesList = ['Root/', 'Root/folder 1/', 'Root/folder 1/Subfolder 1/', 'Root/folder 1/Subfolder 1/textfile.txt', 'Root/folder 2/'];
var $a = $("#a");
$a.html("");
var $files = $("<ul>");
$a.append($files);
filesList.forEach(function(e) {
  $files.append($("<li>", {
    text: e
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a"></div>
```

I want to achieve a full folder type structure while looping through my `filesList`, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Desired results]

Is it possible to achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: Yes it's very posible, what have you tried.

Comment: Do you have control of the input array? This would be trivial if you can change it to a more appropriate structure, such as an array of nested objects.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen - I am trying the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578697/convert-indented-text-list-to-html-list-jquery  @Rory Unfortunately I don't because I am using `jszip` plugin  (https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to read a zip file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this in 3 steps

- Split each array item by `/`
- Create a structured `JSON` object from splited items arrary
- Build HTML tree structure from `JSON`

**Step 1:** Split array items

```
var filesList = [{List Of String Path}];
var finalArray = [];
    filesList.forEach(e) {
          var arr = e.split('/');
          finalArray.push(arr);
         });
```

**Step 2:** Build JSON Tree Structure

```
var tree = makeATree(finalArray);
```

Where `makeATree` function (taken from [stephanbogner/index.js](https://gist.github.com/stephanbogner/4b590f992ead470658a5ebf09167b03d) ) is the following

```
function makeATree(paths) {
                var tree = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
                    var path = paths[i];
                    var currentLevel = tree;
                    for (var j = 0; j < path.length; j++) {
                        var part = path[j];

                        var existingPath = findWhere(currentLevel, 'text', part);

                        if (existingPath) {
                            currentLevel = existingPath.children;
                        } else {
                            var newPart = {
                                text: part,
                                children: [],
                            }

                            currentLevel.push(newPart);
                            currentLevel = newPart.children;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return tree;

                function findWhere(array, key, value) {
                    t = 0;
                    while (t < array.length && array[t][key] !== value) { t++; };

                    if (t < array.length) {
                        return array[t]
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Step 3:** Pretty easy, using the [jstree](https://www.jstree.com/) render it

```
var str = JSON.stringify(tree, null, 4);
$('#DIV').jstree({
   'core': {
       'data': $.parseJSON(str)
       }
});
```

The results are pretty

[image: results]

Hope this helps someone, ask if you have any questions.

FYI I am using [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) to read paths in a zip file, so passing `var filesList = [{List Of String Path}];` manually or have jszip pass it in `JSZip.loadAsync(files[i])`

Please feel free to suggest any better way